# sql2005- how to run a saves ssis package?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

i used management studio to import data from Excel to a SQL table, and on the final step saved the ssis package to the database.

now i want to re-run the saved package on a new excel file i get as a data dump from another system.

the excel file is identical and only the data changes.

how can i re-run the saved ssis package on the new file?

i am just over-writing the old excel file with the new one and expect the ssis job to just pick up everything and run as it did the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run DTExecUI from the command prompt. From here select the server you want to use and the package.